# Why does my CSS animation not work on my sidebar?

Tags: css

Good Day, I'm trying to create a slidedown menu using some JS and CSS but it's not working. Here's the fiddle link:

```
ul.show-child{
height: auto;
display: block;
-webkit-transition: height 1s ease;
-moz-transition: ease-in 2s none;
-ms-transition: ease-in  2s none;
-o-transition: ease-in  2s none;
transition: ease-in  2s none;  
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gkrja9jy/

What I want to do, is to add some cool animation when I show the hidden div. By the way, I just copied the transition effect from this [site](http://davidwalsh.name/css-slide)

Comment: Take a look at this maybe: https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-hoveranimate-one-element-and-animate-another/ ...or if you can stick with JS, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/gkrja9jy/6/  - play around the `stop()` function in that JS example if you don't like the behaviour of the animation e.g. try it with only one `true` argument, or no arguments at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a pure CSS solution. I corrected your example. Make sure that you write correct HTML code. Here is the new code and a fiddle:

HTML code:

```
<ul class="custom-sidebar">
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="post-link">Accountancy</a>
     </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" class="post-link">Grade School</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="post-link">Goals and Objectives</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="post-link">Clubs and Orgs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="post-link">Photo Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="post-link">Summer Tutorial</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS code:

```
li ul {
    display: block;
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
       -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
        -ms-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
         -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
            transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;  
}

li:hover ul {
    height: 100px;
    display: block;

}

.custom-sidebar a,.custom-sidebar a:visited {
    color: #0f5882;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: -23px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.custom-sidebar li {
    list-style: outside none none;
    padding-left: 17px;
}

.custom-sidebar li a {
    background-color: #ebecec;
    border-left: 6px solid #116b9e;
    padding-top: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u6yrL0a0/2/

It is usually best to avoid JavaScript if it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you @B. Martin for your answer, and I totally agree with you that its really best to avoid JS if not really needed..

Answer (score 0):

yo can use jquery to create the animation like this:

```
var jq=jQuery.noConflict();
   jq(document).ready(function(){
        jq('.menu-div').hover(function(){
            if(jq(this).children(":first").hasClass('has-child')){
                var thisx = jq(this).children(":first");
                thisx.next('ul').slideDown(1000);

            }
        });
    });

   jq(document).ready(function(){
        jq('.menu-div').mouseleave(function(){
            if(jq(this).children(":first").hasClass('has-child')){
                var thisx = jq(this).children(":first");
                 thisx.next('ul').slideUp(1000);
            }
        });
    });
```

and the css will be like this :

```
ul.hide-child{
    display: none;
    overflow: hidden;

}
ul li ul{
     -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ;
    transition: all 1s;   
    display:none;
    height:auto;
}

.custom-sidebar .post-link,.post-link:visited{
    color: #0f5882;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    padding-left: 23px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100% !important;
}

.custom-sidebar li{
    background-color: #ebecec;
    border-left: 6px solid #116b9e;
    list-style: outside none none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 17px;
    padding-top: 2px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gkrja9jy/5/

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Moneer Kamal, but isnt there a way to do this with CSS? Coz I see alot of them on tutorials but I cant make it work on mine.. anyways thanks a lot for the effort